# css: hide input file button

Tags: html, css

I have this form for sending multiple files and I'm trying to hide the browse button and leave the text and the surrounding area that is still clickable, maybe by changing the color of the box when the mouse is over and to get the appropiate cursor over the buttons.
Could someone help me to improve it? CSS is often a problem for me, i also can't get the two green canvas of the same height..

[image]

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Upload Multiple Files with Progress Bar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="status"></div>

  <!-- multiple file upload form -->
  <form action="24.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" id="files" class="button">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="button">
  </form>

  <!-- progress bar -->
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="bar">&nbsp;</div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 

$max_size = round(disk_free_space("/var/www") / 2);
$extensions = array('1080.mp4','720.mp4','360.mp4','180.mp4');
$dir = 'new/';
$count = 0;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($_FILES['files']))
{
  // loop all files
  foreach ( $_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name )
  {
    // if file not uploaded then skip it
    if ( !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i]) )
      continue;

      // skip large files
    if ( $_FILES['files']['size'][$i] >= $max_size )
      continue;

    // skip unprotected files
    if( !in_array($name, $extensions) )
      continue;

    // now we can move uploaded files
      if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $dir . $name) )
        $count++;
  }

  echo json_encode(array('count' => $count));

}

?>
```

**CSS**

```
body,
html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100vh;
background-color: #000000;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=submit] {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.container {
  background: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #4FB522;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #4FB522;
  width: 600px;
}
.status {
  background: #000000;
  color: #4FB522;
  display: none;
  margin: 8px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #4FB522;
 font-family: "Geneva";
position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress {
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
}

.bar {
  background: #4FB522;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
 font-family: "Geneva";
}

.percent {
  color: #466D35;
  left: 48%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
 font-family: "Geneva";
}

input.file {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    -moz-opacity:0 ;
    filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.button {
    background-color: #4FB522; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
margin: 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new button with your custom style. Give it position:absolute property and override the custom upload button.
After that, you can attach a click function to your new button that triggers the upload button

Comment: Thanks ksmskt, may i ask how, css it's a problem for me, i know how to get cursor in css but i can't get the override properly